# How to compare Series string to another string in python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare a string from the Series to a string in Python.
Here it seems to be ok - I get results of trues and falses:

```
domains_types['subtype'].astype(str) == 'Default'
```

for a file:
[print(domains_types)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcfrp.png)

But when I try to use it in "if", some problem appears: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
if domains_types['subtype'].astype(str) == 'Default':
    domains_types['Category'] = 'e-commerce'
else:
    domains_types['Category'] = 'other'
```

I'm new in Python, could you please explain there is the problem here and how to solve it?

I'd like to add a new column with a 'Category" according to the 'sybtype'
[result I want, here there is only "other" category so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFBV.png)

Comment: What the list of Series looks like and what is the expected output. Could you give an example?

Comment: `domains_types['subtype'].astype(str) == 'Default'` will return a *new numpy array* with the equality operation done *elementwise*. So you will end up with something like `array([True, True, False])`. You need to be explicity if you want `.any()` or `.all()`, numpy won't guess for you.

Comment: I tried .any() and .all() but really don't understand how numpy works :( I'd rather use just a "normal" for. But don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cat(val):
    if val == 'Default':
        return('e-commerce')
    else:
        return('other')

df['Category'] = df.apply(lambda x: cat(x['Subtype']), axis=1)
```

This should return either 'other' or 'e-commerce' dependent on the value of each value in Subtype column. The issue with making an equivalence check against the whole series is explained above.

Or if you wanted to use a "normal" for loop you can iterate over the dataframe something like:

```
newcol = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Subtype == 'Default':
        newcol.append('e-commerce')
    else:
        newcol.append('other')

df['Category'] = newcol
```

Comment: @adelia-gataullina  does either of these answer your question?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but so far it didn't work

Comment: everything is fine. I've found some spelling misprint in my code. thanks

Comment: @AdeliaGataullina if the above answered the question, please mark it as the accepted answer, thanks